delete excel column using office scripts
I am trying to do a simple delete of column A through column E but can't seem to get anything working.
I tried the record feature to insert code but this comment is all that gets inserted. I have tried searching every way I can think of but mostly keep getting VBA results.
// Delete range I:I on selectedSheet

I have tried these...
selectedSheet.getRange("A:E").delete();
selectedSheet.getRange("A:E").delete;

not sure if this matters but the file is a .csv
needing column A through E to be deleted so that column F is now in the A position.

It would be useful for you to show us the code you have tried so far and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result

I just updated my post to include what I have tried.  I am new to using Office-scripts so i dont  have much to go on.  The "insert action" button only produced a note and no code.

I assume you assigned the correct sheet to selectedSheet? What if you add the shift parameter to the delete? selectedSheet.getRange("A:E").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left)

I found a solution in case anyone else has trouble with this. There may be a more concise way to do this but this works...
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let dcol = selectedSheet.getRange("a:e")
    
    dcol.delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);
    }


Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.Range interface delete method

